# Sync Gradle Error When I try to add "compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'" on my build.gradle dependencies

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to implement a Facebook login feature on my app and I followed every step until  I encountered an "Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'" error. It says :

```
Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(26.0.0-alpha1) from [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1] AndroidManifest.xml:27:9-38
    is also present at [com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1] AndroidManifest.xml:24:9-31 value=(25.3.1).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest.xml:25:5-27:41 to override.
```

[image: I don't know how to execute the suggestions and I am in dire need of help] [EDIT]Thank you in advance guys. [I am not sure how to add files so here's a picture of the build.gradle file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OHz8.png)

Comment: post your `build.gradle` file

Comment: post your complete gradle...

Comment: Do you mean attaching the actual build.gradle file? I can see two build.gradles under Gradle Scripts

Answer (score 0):

You have dependency conflicts. Make sure all your `com.android.support:..` imports are of the same version e.g. `25.0.0` and use fixed versions not `26+` as this can also cause problems.

edit: change `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26+` to `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1`

Comment: Hi @Ryan I am just following a tutorial at the moment and I did all the steps exactly as they were mentioned. I tried syncing build.gradle without this line of code "compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)' "                                                      and it syncs fine, but when I do add it and sync, it gives an error

Comment: The Facebook SDK uses 25.3.1, so I'd suggest setting your `com.android.support` modules to 25.3.1 - https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/facebook/build.gradle